# How to calculate the distances of two firms for 200000 firms using Python?

Tags: python, bigdata

```
import math
def cal_dis(latitude1, longitude1,latitude2, longitude2): 
    latitude1 = (math.pi/180.0)*latitude1
    latitude2 = (math.pi/180.0)*latitude2 
    longitude1 = (math.pi/180.0)*longitude1
    longitude2= (math.pi/180.0)*longitude2
    R = 6378.1  
    temp=sin(latitude1)*sin(latitude2) + 
         cos(latitude1)*cos(latitude2)*cos(longitude2-longitude1)  
    if repr(temp)>1.0:  
        temp = 1.0  
    dist = acos(temp)*R  
    return dist;
#调用函数
for la, lg in zip(data1['lat'], data1['lng']):
    d = map(cal_dis, la, lg)
    list(d)
```

I want to use `map` to invoke `cal_dis` function, but How could I calculate the distances of two firms for 200000 firms using Python?
Does there exit running more speeder methods?

Comment: I think a list comprehension would be a little faster than `map`. Also, you have a bunch of redundant calculations that you could pre-compute and cache.

Comment: Do you want to find the difference between _every_ pair of locations? That's a _lot_ of pairs! BTW, your `cal_dis` takes 4 args, but your `map` call only supplies 2 args, so it won't work.

Comment: Also, the Earth isn't a perfect sphere, so those distances will only be roughly correct. There are various ways to get more accurate distances. For points of similar latitude, it's quite easy: you can apply a simple scaling factor. Otherwise, you need to use proper ellipsoid geodesic calculations, which are a lot slower than simple spherical trig, although there are good libraries that can do it. I use & recommend Karney's [geographiclib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/), which is far more accurate than the old Vincenty's formulae.